# Do python have syntactic sugar "condition?c:d"

Tags: python

Java, c, c++ both have syntactic sugar like this:

```
int a = condition ? c : d// if condition is true , a = c, else a = d
```

Do python have similar syntactic sugar?

Comment: Now all it needs is `++` rather than `+= 1` :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes :)

```
a = c if condition else d
```

This was introduced in Python 2.5

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't have a classic "?" ternary operator, but does have a similar construct:

```
result = 'I am True' if condition else 'I am False'
```

Answer (score 1):

see the example:- [python ternory operator](http://northisup.com/blog/the-ternary-operator-in-python/)

```
syntax:-  a if test else b

In [54]: 'true' if True else 'false'
Out[54]: 'true'
```

so that:-

```
In [52]: a = 5 if 2> 3 else 3

In [53]: a
Out[53]: 3
```